# Circular GameScene in Spritekit

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

How can I make a spritekit scene have a circular gamescene (or at least a circular physics body).

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let box = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
        box.position = location
        box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
        addChild(box)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        scene.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 150)
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

I tried adding a physicsbody to the scene, but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

`scene.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 150)`

I can crop the view to a circle using SwiftUI, but the spawned squares will partially disappear from view without a properly set up circle collider to contain them.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding an SKShapeNode constructed with a path and then cutting out a circle using swiftui.

Final functional code

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let box = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
        box.position = location
        box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
        addChild(box)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let path = Path { path in
        let center = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150)
        let radius: CGFloat = 150
        path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360), clockwise: true)
    }
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill

        // Circular container for objects
        let containerCircle = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)
        containerCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        containerCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: path.cgPath)
        scene.addChild(containerCircle)
        
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            // Crop shape so we don't see out of bounds activity
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}
```